# Could not upgrade RDL on Report

Tags: docker, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I'm getting error when importing report (as text file) to database (Nav 2017 CU11).

```
: [21431012] Could not upgrade RDL on Report XXXXXX Report Name.
', hexadecimal value 0x14, is an invalid character. Line 8693, position 64.
[0] The import stopped at line 2810411.
```

The thing is that I'm only getting this error when trying to import this object inside the docker container. DB and service tier are hosted inside the same container.

Same object works/imports fine on regular PC. Nav versions exactly the same on PC and in the container.

Moreover there is not a single place in the text file where I could find mentioned `0x14` character.

As far as I know `Line 8693, position 64.` refers to the RDLc part of the text file. At this position stands legit letter `й` (Russian).

It must have something to do with encoding but I found no way to play with it inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is the language settings/localization/locale in(side) the container?
Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture?view=win10-ps) will help...

Cheers

Comment: Tried everything I could: Set-WinSystemLocale ru-RU
    Set-Culture ru-RU
    [Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("ru-RU")
    [Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("ru-RU")

Comment: That's a shame... Have tried to report it to Microsoft?

Comment: Nope. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, try to comment here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2017/10/05/cumulative-update-11-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2017-has-been-released/ they usually reply